# trouble with relative imports

Tags: ironpython

EDIT: is `from __future__ import absolute_import` available in IronPython? I just realized, though everything I'm using is only python, the project as a whole is in IronPython.

I'm trying to use relative imports (instead of appending to sys.path). Here is my directory structure:

```
-src
  |
  -runners
    |
    -__init__.py
    -clippyRunner.py
  |
  -__init__.py
  -clippy.py
  -irondb.py
  -ironxl.py
```

now, in clippyRunner.py, I want to import clippy, which as you can see is in the parent directory `src`. so what I've done is this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from ...src import clippy
```

but this is giving me this error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

i've also tried

```
from ..src import clippy
```

witht he same results.

what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I've also tried `import ..clippy`
which just gives me: `SyntaxError: unexpected token '.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're getting says that IronPython is accepting the syntax, but believes you aren't currently running code inside a package.

Since you're getting `'__main__'` instead of `'src.runners.clippyRunner'` when you print out `__name__`, this tells me that you're running `/src/runners/clippyRunner.py` directly from the command line. As you've seen, this breaks relative imports, since Python doesn't know where the module lives in the package heirarchy.

In CPython, you can handle this situation by using the command line `python -m src.runners.clippyRunner` from the directory containing the `src` package to ensure the interpreter knows the proper location of the affected module.

I don't know if the current version of IronPython has an equivalent mechanism (CPython only fixed it when PEP 366 was included in version 2.6)

Comment: when I print `__name__` I get `__main__`

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly - there are issues when trying to perform relative imports from the main module.

Answer (score 1):

Your import is broken:

```
 from .. import clippy
```

Comment: should've mentioned that I tried that, too. but I get a 'SyntaxError: unexpected token '.'`